# Change number of products per page in prestashop backoffice stock management

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I need to change the number of products showing in **prestashop1.7 backoffice stock management section**. There is no dropdown available to choose the number of products showing per page. So, is it possible to have this option or change the number of products per page in backoffice stock management section ?

Comment: Is not clear what are you looking for changing the number of products per page in Stock Management section, what you can do is use the filter by category or supplier to reduce the qty of products displayed.

In any case you have to take a look inside the .php file who truncate this qty in the backoffice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.